# Ruby/Rails expansion of the if block from one line - rubocop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I have to modify my if block from one line.

```
def filename
 "#{model.external_id}-inquiry_process_summary_#{timestamp}.pdf" if original_filename
end
```

to something like this:

```
def filename
  if original_filename
    result = model.inquiry_field_responses.joins(:inquiry_field).where(inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' })
    "#{result.first&.value}-inquiry_process_summary_#{timestamp}.pdf"
  end
end
```

This is simple but my rubocop's screaming `Use a guard clause instead of wrapping the code inside a conditional expression`. If I add `Success` before last `end` few of my specs fail with error

> expected the response to have status code (422) but it was :ok (200)

Without `Success` everything pass as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, Rubocop is complaining about not returning early. This should solve the Rubocop problem:

```
def filename
  return unless original_filename

  result = model.inquiry_field_responses.joins(:inquiry_field).where(inquiry_fields: { name: 'company_name' })
  "#{result.first&.value}-inquiry_process_summary_#{timestamp}.pdf"
end
```

Read more about the [guard clause](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Cop/Style/GuardClause).